# React setState call not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a React setState call that is choosing to misbehave, and I can't figure out what's going on. I think I've got it narrowed down a fair bit - this is the method in question:

```
  setShowDeleteEventModal = (value) => {
    console.log('dude', value); //logs true
    this.setState(() => ({ showDeleteEventModal: value }), () => {
      console.log('hey', this.state); //logs state showing 'showDeleteEventModal: false'
    });
  };
```

What I've done so far:

Checked to see if it's async - it isn't, based on the problem showing up in the callback function, though I also used a setTimeout to check it;
Made sure I have state properly declared;
Checked spelling on my variables, including using Find to make sure they all show up under the same spelling;
Checked the type of value in case it was a String - it's a boolean;
Rewrote the entire implementation.

Desired behavior: showDeleteEventModal shows up true after the setState call.
Actual behavior: it doesn't.

I call this method from a button onClick in a sub-component, but since 'dude' and 'true' show up to the screen I know it's getting into here. showDeleteEventModal is a switch that controls whether a modal is displayed or not.

The part that baffles me most about it is that I have an extremely similar setup in the same file which works flawlessly. Here is the other method:

```
setShowOnMap = (value) => {
  this.setState(() => ({ showOnMap: value }));
};
```

And here is the button call from the subcomponent with the prop being passed in:

```
<div className = "button background-red width15"
          onClick = {props.switchModals}
        >
          Remove this event
        </div>

switchModals = {
  () => {
    this.setShowDeleteEventModal(true);
    this.closeModal()
  }
}
```

The whole file is a little long for posting here, but hopefully this will be enough and I'm just missing something silly.

Answer (score 2):

```
setShowDeleteEventModal = (value) => {
  console.log('dude', value); //logs true
  this.setState({ showDeleteEventModal: value }, () => {
    console.log('hey', this.state); //logs state showing 'showDeleteEventModal: false'
  });
};
```

Try to remove the arrow function call, for your first parameter just put the state object instead, just like above

Comment: Correct. This https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate and this https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b will help.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything. I've used the callback syntax for everything I've done in React for months, and every other instance of it in my project is working. It must be something else?